# ¿Cómo comparar la misma cadena de string en php?

Tags: php, array

Lo que tengo es un array que manda lo siguiente:

```
> Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
)
Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
    [1] => CTS-005X000S101
)
Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
    [1] => CTS-005X000S101
    [2] => 9327279-0
)
Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
    [1] => CTS-005X000S101
    [2] => 9327279-0
    [3] => 9311321-0
)
Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
    [1] => CTS-005X000S101
    [2] => 9327279-0
    [3] => 9311321-0
    [4] => CTS-005X000S101
)
Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
    [1] => CTS-005X000S101
    [2] => 9327279-0
    [3] => 9311321-0
    [4] => CTS-005X000S101
    [5] => CTS-015X000S101
)
Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
    [1] => CTS-005X000S101
    [2] => 9327279-0
    [3] => 9311321-0
    [4] => CTS-005X000S101
    [5] => CTS-015X000S101
    [6] => 9327279-0
)
Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
    [1] => CTS-005X000S101
    [2] => 9327279-0
    [3] => 9311321-0
    [4] => CTS-005X000S101
    [5] => CTS-015X000S101
    [6] => 9327279-0
    [7] => 9327279-0
)
Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
    [1] => CTS-005X000S101
    [2] => 9327279-0
    [3] => 9311321-0
    [4] => CTS-005X000S101
    [5] => CTS-015X000S101
    [6] => 9327279-0
    [7] => 9327279-0
    [8] => 9323350-0
)
Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
    [1] => CTS-005X000S101
    [2] => 9327279-0
    [3] => 9311321-0
    [4] => CTS-005X000S101
    [5] => CTS-015X000S101
    [6] => 9327279-0
    [7] => 9327279-0
    [8] => 9323350-0
    [9] => 9323350-0
)
Array
(
    [0] => CTS-005X000S101
    [1] => CTS-005X000S101
    [2] => 9327279-0
    [3] => 9311321-0
    [4] => CTS-005X000S101
    [5] => CTS-015X000S101
    [6] => 9327279-0
    [7] => 9327279-0
    [8] => 9323350-0
    [9] => 9323350-0
    [10] => 9323409-0
)
```

Y lo que tengo que lograr hacer es que cada vez que se "repita" un elemento del siguiente array  esta debe eliminarse.

No tengo un código pre definido solo tengo esa salida. si tuviera que crear un código seria algo así.

```
   foreach ($listSkus->list as $key => $sku1) {
    foreach($listSkus->list as $key => $sku2){
        $array1[] = $sku1->sku;
        $array2[] = $sku2->sku;
            if($array1 == $array2){
                unset($array1);
                unset($array2);
            }else{
                print_r("<pre>");
                print_r($array1);
                print_r("</pre>");
            }
    }   

}
```

La verdad necesito ideas como recorrer fila por fila y comparándolas... Talvez con un for u while si tienen referencias se agradecería.

Comment: Hola! Pregunta: quieres decir que, si tienes diez arrays y un elemento del array 1 se repite en el array 8, ¿debe eliminarse de dónde? o ¿quieres tener un único array donde estén todos los diferentes valores de los N arrays de entrada, sin repetición?

Comment: @Alfabravo Exacto así mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea es que hagas la opción más barata, sin anidar cosas. Entonces, en vez de anidar y tener un algoritmo O(n^2), arma un `$arrayDefinitivo` y ve añadiendo ahí los elementos de cada array de entrada, validando antes que no estén.

Entonces, para cada elemento de cada array de entrada (que sólo debes recorrer una vez), vas buscando si hay un elemento con ese valor para ver si lo añades o no.

```
$key = array_search('CTS-005X000S101', $arrayDefinitivo);
if (!$key){
    array_push($arrayDefinitivo, 'CTS-005X000S101');
}
```

La salida será ese arrayDefinitivo...

Puedes usar la extensión PHP-DS si tienes PHP >= 7 https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ds.php